# With my session counter of visitors is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my code, if user visit then it increases counts but it gives me an error

```
/home/u845,409,439/domains/jamiatulamasolapur.org/public_html/application/views/home.php Line: 161 Function: fread File: /home/u845,409,439/domains/jamiatulamasolapur.org/public_html/application/controllers/MainController.php Line: 46 Function: view File: /home/u845,409,439/domains/jamiatulamasolapur.org/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
Visitor
```

My code:

```
<?php
// session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
 $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
 fwrite($f,"0");
 fclose($f);
}

// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
 $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
 $counterVal++;
 $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
 fwrite($f, $counterVal);
 fclose($f);
}
echo "$counterVal";

?>
```

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.

Comment: `$counter_name = "<?php echo base_url();?>";` what is this?

Comment: @u_mulder I change in my code it is `counter.txt` file not  `"<?php echo base_url();?>";` this

Comment: What is the actual error message? What you have shown in the first block lists script file names, line numbers and function names - but there doesn’t appear to be an actual _error message_ in there.

Comment: In your real code you don’t have the session_start line commented out, right? Or are you picking up the session before that point already?

Comment: @04FS Yes it is commented I am not picking up session before that time

Comment: Well then it makes no sense that you are trying to use `$_SESSION` further down the script. You _always_ need to pick the session up again by calling `session_start`.